# Knockout array being displayed as a function, not the contents

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-postbox

I have the following:

```
this.testArray = ko.observableArray(["a", "b"]);
this.publishedSelectedSets = ko.observableArray().subscribeTo("SELECTED_SETS");
```

Then in my view I have:

```
<span data-bind="text: testArray "></span>
<span data-bind="text: publishedSelectedSets "></span>
```

I'd expect to see `a,b` and then a list of the contents of publishedSelectedSets (just numbers), but what gets displayed is:

> SELECTED SET IDS: a,b
>
> function observable() { if (arguments.length > 0) { // Write // Ignore
>   writes if the value hasn't changed if
>   ((!observable['equalityComparer']) ||
>   !observable['equalityComparer'](_latestValue, arguments[0])) {
>   observable.valueWillMutate(); _latestValue = arguments[0]; if (DEBUG)
>   observable._latestValue = _latestValue; observable.valueHasMutated();
>   } return this; // Permits chained assignments } else { // Read
>   ko.dependencyDetection.registerDependency(observable); // The caller
>   only needs to be notified of changes if they did a "read" operation
>   return _latestValue; } }

I tried adding parentheses at the end of `publishedSelectedSets()` but I get the same thing.  I can use the debugger to see `_latestValue` updating correctly for the `publishedSelectedSets` array, but the data isn't displaying correctly in the DOM.

What am I doing wrong?

SELECTED_SETS:

```
this.selectedSets = ko.computed(

    function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(ko.utils.arrayFilter(vm.data.sets(), function (set) {
            return set.isSelected();
        }), function (set) { return set.setId; });

    }).publishOn("SELECTED_SETS");
```

JSFiddle which is working, with a simplified use of ko.utils.arrayMap: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/80/

Still can't figure out why my code isn't working...

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle that shows your problem?

Comment: What is publishing to `SELECTED_SETS`?

Comment: @JeffMercado - a computed array.  I just updated my post to show this

Comment: @ColinDeClue I tried but couldn't get the subscriptions to work properly on jsFiddle.  I'll try again

Comment: You probably need to include knockout-postbox in the fiddle as well.

Comment: @ColinDeClue - I've no clue what's going on.  It's working in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/80/

Comment: If your `setId` is an `ko.observable` then you need `function (set) { return set.setId(); }`...

Comment: @nemesv - that did the trick.  Those parentheses have something against me.  Feel free to post up as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `publishedSelectedSets` array contains `ko.observable` functions that is why you get the strange output.

And you have observable functions in your array because of your map method:

```
function (set) { return set.setId; }
```

Where you are returning the observable function itself with the `set.setId` and not its value.

To fix it just put out the `()`

```
function (set) { return set.setId(); }
```